# Empty Emails Being Sent Laravel 8.*

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am trying to send confirmation emails to my users through my laravel app. Empty Emails are being sent.
I am using a aws server. I tried changing the file names. Changing the permissions, user and groups of the server. any of those did not work. for me.

my controller:

```
 Mail::to($req->input('useremail'))->send(new CustomerCreated($user));
```

My Mailer Class

```
    <?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class CustomerCreated extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public $user;

    public function __construct($user)
    {
        //
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.customercreation')->subject('User Created.');
    }
}
```

My Email template

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Account Created Successfully</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>sdsadasd</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

My ENV

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxx@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=xxxxxx@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="XXX"
```

This is what i get.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

One thing I can see wrong right off the bat is your mail config for gmail. It should be something like this to use gmail according to their docs. You also have to enable smtp from your app.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxx@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

This may not be the ultimate problem. After that's fixed and app permissions are given then you can jump down the rabbit hole to see what's really wrong.

Comment: I tried it already.